# How to tell if plugin were added to a Foreman installation

Tags: foreman

I am planning a migration from an old Foreman install to a new version and a new server.
I wish to know how can I find out if any plugins were added to the old installation and so that I can install them on the new system as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some answers I got on the Foreman IRC channel:

- First place to look -> The 'about' page, it lists all properly registered plugins (But some plugins may not register)
- 2nd place -> the OS packaging system - many plugins are installed as packages with names that include 'foreman' somewhere
- 3rd place -> the gem command - run 'gem list' with the foreman user, look for gems that have 'foreman' in their names.
- If you suspect there are faulty/unregisted plugins:
  Foreman actually looks for plugins in its Gemfile, or in files in the 'bundler.d' directory under the Foreman installation directory. If its not there, Foreman does not load it.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to add 1 additional way to do this:

You can use the Foreman API to get information on the installed plugins:

```
curl -sS -u username:password 'https://foreman_server/api/v2/plugins?per_page=1000'
```

Additionally you can pipe the result to jq-linux64 (The command-line JSON processor) for some nice output.

Comment: adding `| jq -r ".results[].id"` and `| head` gives some high level info easy to share.